# Where can I find an EBNF grammar of Objective-C 2.0

Tags: objective-c, grammar

I'm learning Objective-C. I want to know the detail of its grammar.
So where can I find an EBNF grammar of Objective-C 2.0?
I tried to search on http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/
but can not find useful information.

Comment: @Alex Apparently OP does.

Comment: Here's [a grammar](https://github.com/itod/parsekit/blob/master/res/objc.grammar), for example.

Comment: EBNF grammars are hard to come by in general; it is a standard that's widely ignored.  The grammar linked to is only 236 lines long; it isn't complete, and it isn't in EBNF.  It has some useful info in it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a detailed Objective-C 2.0 grammar on this page:
https://github.com/iamdc/Objective-C-Grammar/blob/master/ObjC.Grm